# Could someone explain this notation to me? [Linear Algebra]

Tags: linear-algebra

Shown in part (a) in the image below, in which I'm asked to check if a given set forms a basis for $\mathbb R[t]_{\leqslant 3}$. Could someone explain in plain words what is denoted by $\mathbb R[t]_{\leqslant 3}$?

[image: Image Here]

Comment: This is the vector space of polynomials in 1 viariable $t$ with degree less or equal to $3$. It has dimension $4$ since you can write every element using $1,t,t^2,t^3$ and they are linearly independent because $at^3 + bt^2+ ct+d =0 \iff a=b=c=d=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the set of polynomials in the variable $t$ with real coefficients and degree at most 3:
$$
\mathbb R [t]_{\leq 3} = \left\{ \sum_{i=0}^3 a_i t^i \; \middle| \; a_0, \dots, a_3 \in \mathbb R \right\}
$$

Comment: Ah it could be something to do with the degree of the polynomials, we haven't touched on rings yet though.

Comment: Replace the word "ring" with the word "set", then

Comment: There is no ring of polynomials of degree at most $3$, it isn't closed under products.

Comment: @ninkle A "ring" is, essentially, any set where you can add, subtract, and multiply the elements to each other and get something else in the set. (There are some finer points but that's the basic gist.)

Comment: You're right, I should have said "set"

Comment: Replace set with vector space, since this is what we are talking about!

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R[t]$ (without the $\le\!3$) refers to the set of all polynomials with real coefficients where the variable is $t$:
$$\Bbb R[t]=\{a_0+a_1t+\dotsb+a_nt^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\land a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb R\}$$
For example, $42.3x^{100}+\sqrt2x^9-x^2-\pi x+3$ is an element of $\Bbb R[t]$.

Given the context, it would seem $\Bbb R[t]_{\le3}$ would be the set of polynomials with real coefficients where the variable is $t$ and the degree is at most $3$:
$$\Bbb R[t]=\{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3\mid a_0,a_1,a_2,a_n\in\Bbb R\}$$
For example, $42.3x^3+\sqrt2x^2-\pi x+3$ is an element of $\Bbb R[t]$.